# "Bumped to the homepage" notice with wrong date

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-user, bump

In this [LQP review](//stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14552023) I see a rather strange notice:

[image]

I know that our dear Community♦ bot bumps upvoted questions without upvoted answers when it's bored — and this [last happened about 8 hours ago](//stackoverflow.com/posts/26276580/timeline) for this question — but Oct 9 '14 is the date this question was *asked*, not when it was last bumped. So that date is wrong.

I also can't recall ever seeing this notice before, and it's only visible in the review (not when actually loading the question) — so I'm not sure if displaying this in the first place is intentional.

Comment: The notice is new (been around for a week or two). I don't think we accounted for it getting displayed in review. It should never show up there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've corrected the code to use the right date for display.

With you in the next build.

Answer (score 12):

This is the logic for that notice:

```
@if (!q.IsClosed && q.LastActivityUserId == COMMUNITY_USER_ID 
      && q.LastActivityTypeId == LastActivityTypeId.Modified
      && q.LastActivityDate.AddDays(CommunityBumpMessageDisplayDays) > Current.Time)
{
    if (q.HasRecentBumpHistory)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="post-notice" colspan="2">
                <div class="question-status">
                    <h2>@_m("**Bumped to the homepage by Community $when$**", 
                        new { when = q.LastEditDate.ToRelativeTime(false) })</h2>
                    <p>@_s("This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed.")</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

Emphasis mine. The right date is being checked for activity (`LastActivityDate`), but the wrong date is being used for the actual message (`LastEditDate`).

Related: ["Bumped to the homepage by Community" after suggested edit approved by Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287445/bumped-to-the-homepage-by-community-after-suggested-edit-approved-by-community)

Comment: So… will it be fixed?

Comment: Probably? I expect Oded's asleep right now, but soon, like the moon, he will rise.

Comment: Someone called???